# People picker get value in form JQuery SP 2013

Tags: 2013, jquery

How is get value People Picker JQuery SP 2013? Isn't work my code ((

[image]

```
function _spBodyOnLoad(){
var pickerPeople = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict['User'].GetAllUserInfo();
if (pickerPeople.length > 0) {
    alert("User: " + pickerPeople[0].DisplayText);
} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code might helps you

```
var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;
    // Get the people picker object from the page.
    for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
        peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
    }
    if (peoplePicker != null) {
        // Get information about all users.
        var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
        var userInfo = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            userInfo += user['Key'] + ";#";
        }
        return userInfo;
    }
```

Comment: var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict['User'] error is null?

Comment: How did you bind people picker? did you use sppeoplepicker.js?

Comment: I'm using sppeoplepicker.js return is blank